# Receiving streamed data using Fetch API in Firefox

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, fetch

I am sending data in chunks from a Node.js server whenever a request comes. Expressjs is used.

```js
router.post('/api/test', (req, res) => {
    console.log("Started api servicing");
    let interval = setInterval(() => {
        res.write("Message");
    }, 500);
    setTimeout(() =>  {
        clearInterval(interval);
        res.end("Done");
    }, 1000*10);
})
```

This sends `"Message"` 20 times over a duration of 10 seconds.

This endpoint is called from the client side using Fetch API. The idea is that I should be able to receive each of the `"Message"` individually on the client side and this is the implementation I've come up with.

```js
fetch('/api/test', { method: 'POST' })
    .then(res => res.body.getReader())
    .then(reader => processData(reader))

function processData(reader) {
    reader.read().then(({value, done}) => {
        console.log(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, value));
        if (!done) {
            processData(reader)
        }
    })
    return null;
}
```

I expected the handler function to console log each time `"Message"` is sent from server i.e every 0.5 second. But in firefox, only after 10 seconds, all the data is console logged at once like:
`"MessageMessageMessageMessageMessageMessageMessageMessageMessageMessageMessageMessageMessageMessageMessageMessageMessageMessageMessageDone"`

It works correctly in Chrome i.e `"Message"` is console logged every 0.5 seconds.

Why is this happening and how to fix this behaviour in Firefox?

Comment: this kind stream (http) doesn't work the way you want. Take a look at sockets https://socket.io/

Comment: @Grynets Thanks for the suggestion. But in chrome this method seems to work fine.. its just in firefox I am not getting the desired functionality

Answer (score 2):

This question is old but I was having the same issue. I solved it by adding the content type header to the response:

```
res.setHeader('content-type', 'text/plain');
```